Ion-Searchbar not showing on native Android device
When I run my angular (ionic) app on the browser everything works and looks fine. (Angular v17.0.2, Ionic v8.2.2).
When I npx cap sync it and try it out on a device with Android Studio it looks like the second image I added. There is nothing wrong with the z-index, I already checked that. The html and css is pretty simple, so I don't get what's wrong here.
<ion-row class="search">
<ion-col size="10">
<ion-searchbar #input (search)="searchJobs(input.value)" (keydown.enter)="searchJobs(input.value)" placeholder="Search For Jobs"></ion-searchbar>
</ion-col>
<ion-col size="2">
<ion-button mode="ios" class="ion-align-self-center" (click)="toggleModal()">
<ion-icon name="options"></ion-icon>
</ion-button>
</ion-col>
</ion-row>

CSS:
ion-row.search {
padding-right: 1.5vh;
align-items: center;

ion-searchbar {
display: flex;
height: 50px;
width: 100%; /* Ensure it takes full width */
--background: white;
--border-radius: 10px;
}
}

Browser: https://i.sstatic.net/BY1R2fzu.png
Android Studio: https://i.sstatic.net/BHRrHBJz.png

Did you run: ionic build and then npx cap sync? Also try to remove your extra styles and check to see if it even shows up.

Yes i did.. still got the same issue tho

are there any errors shown in console log? recreate a reproducible example using stackblitz and post link here.

Check Viewport Meta Tag: Ensure that the viewport meta tag is correctly set in your index.html. This can greatly affect how content scales on different devices. It should look something like this:
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
Device Specific Styles: Sometimes, styles need to be adjusted specifically for mobile devices. You can use media queries to add styles that only apply to smaller screens or specific devices:
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) { ion-searchbar { height: 40px; // Adjust height for mobile devices } }

I tried your  approach, however its not much different from what i already have and it still doesnt work. The styles you did with @media dont matter, I dont have to change anything there, since i already develop for mobile devices (in the browser view)...
